# Core Plot Scrolling

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using the plot Interaction property set to YES to allow scrolling. Now it allows scrolling on the axes till infinity and also on the negative side of the axes . How can the scrolling be restricted only along the horizontal axis and also not extending upto infinity on the same axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `globalYRange` to limit the zooming and scrolling along the y-axis. If you need more control, use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space and respond accordingly. There are several examples in the *Plot Gallery* example app.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It works setting the globalYRange . And also thanks for writing Core Plot :)

Comment: How to restrict zooming only along the X-axis. I want the Y-axis to remain same while zooming ; so want to enable zooming only in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Use a plot space delegate and don’t allow the `yRange` to change.

Comment: Okay. Will try doing it.Thanks.